# Configuring Two Way Client Auth SSL Certificate on Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2.4

I am currently developing an API to communicate with an external service and they require that we use a two way auth with the certificate they sent.

I have received two files: .pem and .cer, both files have the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

I've tried several different ways to configure this on Apache 2.4, using `SSLCACertificateFile`, but all I get is errors saying it could not start server:

```
[Mon Dec 05 10:29:06.434853 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 6112] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for my-server.com:443
[Mon Dec 05 10:29:06.434872 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 6112] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
```

Would it be possible to configure this auth with just this files, or should I request the .key in order to configure everything?

Best

Answer (score 1):

You can configure two way client Auth SSL certificate by getting third party certificate. Apache works on OpenSSL command so you have to create CSR, private key and install CA bundle and certificate.

Install Root certificate in Apache: https://www.alphassl.com/support/install-root/apache.html

For SSL installation in Apache: https://www.alphassl.com/support/install-ssl/apache.html

I suggest you to read this article which will help you to understand more deeply: http://www.stefanocapitanio.com/configuring-two-way-authentication-ssl-with-apache/